# How to improve time complexity of this snippet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, big-o

I am trying to improve the time complexity and quality of the code snippet below.
I am iterating through one array to check if the element this array exists in the object, should this be true it should return the name matching the element id in the object.
how can I do this without having a nested loop?
Can someone tell me what I can do to make this algo better, please?

Thank you all in advance.

```
let genres = [28, 12, 878];
data = {
  genres: [
    {
      id: 28,
      name: 'Action',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: 'Adventure',
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      name: 'Animation',
    },
    {
      id: 35,
      name: 'Comedy',
    },
    {
      id: 80,
      name: 'Crime',
    },
    {
      id: 99,
      name: 'Documentary',
    },
    {
      id: 18,
      name: 'Drama',
    },
    {
      id: 10751,
      name: 'Family',
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      name: 'Fantasy',
    },
    {
      id: 36,
      name: 'History',
    },
    {
      id: 27,
      name: 'Horror',
    },
    {
      id: 10402,
      name: 'Music',
    },
    {
      id: 9648,
      name: 'Mystery',
    },
    {
      id: 10749,
      name: 'Romance',
    },
    {
      id: 878,
      name: 'Science Fiction',
    },
    {
      id: 10770,
      name: 'TV Movie',
    },
    {
      id: 53,
      name: 'Thriller',
    },
    {
      id: 10752,
      name: 'War',
    },
    {
      id: 37,
      name: 'Western',
    },
  ],
};

const getGenreName = () => {
  let result = [];
  for (let genre of data.genres) {
    //console.log("genre", genre.name)
    for (let id of genres) {
      //console.log('id',genres[i])
      if (id === genre.id) result.push(genre.name);
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
};

getGenreName();
```

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, thanks for helping, id of genres refers to genres [ 28,12,878]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `includes` as others have already shown. This will make the code a bit cleaner, but not change the overall runtime complexity. To improve runtime complexity you may need to use a different data structure.

For instance instead of

```
let genres = [1,2,3,4];
```

as a simple array, you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which has a better lookup performance.

```
let genres = new Set([1,2,3,4]);
```

Then you can use this as follows

```
let result = data.genres
 .filter(g => genres.has(g.id))
 .map(g => g.name);
```

and won't need any explict `for` loops

Answer (score 2):

The simplest improvement would probably be converting `genres` to a Set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
and use the `has` method to check if each id in the data is a member of the set of chosen genres.

You can also convert the data to a map with the ids as the keys in order to look up by id quickly instead of looping, but that is only faster if the data is reused many times.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript `#reduce` in the example outlined below would have O(n) time complexity. This only loops through the array once. We could use filter, and map but it would result in us having to loop through the array twice.

```js
const getGenreName = () => {
    const genreSet = new Set(genres);
    return data.genres.reduce((accumulator, { id, name }) => {
        if (genreSet.has(id)) accumulator.push(name);
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
};

console.log(getGenreName()); // [ 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction' ]
```

We are initializing the reducer to start with the array `[]`, or an empty array, and then checking to see if the `genre` property of the object is included in the `genres` array, if it isn't, return the accumulator, if it is, append it to the end of the accumulator and return it.

Comment: Eventhough you are hiding the loops behind `reduce` and `includes` your snippet has exact the sampe runtime complexity as OPs code. Because internally `reduce` has also to itererate all elements of `data.genres` and `genres.includes` traverses the elements of `genres` in each iteration

Comment: This will still be O(m * n) where m is the size of genres, as includes will iterate over that array internally

Comment: @derpirscher Good point, thank you for outlining. In order to get around `includes` iteration, I've gone ahead and switched the answer to use `Set`, since `has` uses O(1) rather than the `includes` which has O(n).

Comment: thank you all for your contributions.  I don't understand the accumulator I will search  about this so i can understand it better @RidaF'kih

Comment: @JonasHøgh Thank you both for the fantastic point, I've made a couple improvements. Feel free to review. I've switched the answer to use Array push, as spread operator has time complexity of O(n), versus push having O(1), and switched to casting the array to a Set, then using `has` in order to check for presence, reducing from O(n) of `includes` to the O(1)` of `has.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted this in one loop, so here it is:

```js
let result = [];
data.genres.forEach(function (e) {
  if (genres.includes(e.id)) result.push(e.name);
});
console.log(result);
```

In case you were wondering about `forEach`, here's a very good reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Comment: With this solution, forEach has time complexity of O(n), and so does Array `includes`, which also has time complexity of O(n), so this solutions overall time complexity, similarly to my previous solution prior to my edits, is O(m * n).

Answer (score 0):

The current time complexity is O(MN) where M is the length of `data.genres` and N is the length of `genres`.
Time complexity in JavaScript depends on which engine you use, but in most cases you can use a `Map` to reduce this time complexity to O(max{N,M}):

```
const getGenreName = () => {
  const dataGenresMap = new Map( // O(M)
    data.genres.map(({id,...params}) => [id,params]) // O(M)
  )
  let result = []
  for (let id of genres) { // O(N)
    if (dataGenresMap.has(id)) result.push(dataGenresMap.get(id).name) // O(1)
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** you might be doing this more than once then I'd recommend using a `Map`. By creating a hash map, retrieving genre names per id is much more performant.

```
  let genres = [28, 12, 878];
  data = {
    genres: [
      {
        id: 28,
        name: 'Action',
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Adventure',
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        name: 'Animation',
      },
      {
        id: 35,
        name: 'Comedy',
      },
      {
        id: 80,
        name: 'Crime',
      },
      {
        id: 99,
        name: 'Documentary',
      },
      {
        id: 18,
        name: 'Drama',
      },
      {
        id: 10751,
        name: 'Family',
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        name: 'Fantasy',
      },
      {
        id: 36,
        name: 'History',
      },
      {
        id: 27,
        name: 'Horror',
      },
      {
        id: 10402,
        name: 'Music',
      },
      {
        id: 9648,
        name: 'Mystery',
      },
      {
        id: 10749,
        name: 'Romance',
      },
      {
        id: 878,
        name: 'Science Fiction',
      },
      {
        id: 10770,
        name: 'TV Movie',
      },
      {
        id: 53,
        name: 'Thriller',
      },
      {
        id: 10752,
        name: 'War',
      },
      {
        id: 37,
        name: 'Western',
      },
    ],
  };
  
  const genreById = new Map ();
  data.genres.forEach(({id, name}) => genreById.set(id, name));
  
  const pushMapValueIfTruthy = map => array => key => {
    const val = map.get(key);
    if (val) {
      array.push(val);
    }
  };
  
  /** function that takes an array, then id, and pushes corresponding name (if exists) into the array. */
  const pushGenreNaneIfExists = pushMapValueIfTruthy(genreById);
  
  const getGenreNames = (ids) => {
    result = [];
    ids.forEach(pushGenreNaneIfExists(result));
    return result;
  };
  
  console.log(getGenreNames(genres));
```